# Issue pushing large Docker image to Heroku registry

Tags: python, docker, flask, heroku, devops

I have developed a text summarization model and built a Flask application around it. I've successfully containerized it using Docker, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to push the Docker image from Docker Hub to the Heroku registry.

The problem I'm facing is that every time the pushing process reaches 9.31 GB (which is the size of the Docker image), the pushing process restarts. I've attempted various solutions, but none seem to resolve the issue. (there is no problem with Dockerfile and requirements.txt as the image in running perfectly fine locally).

Here are the methods I've tried:

Using the Heroku command:

```
heroku container:login
heroku container:push web
```

Using the Docker command:

```
docker tag <image_id> <username>/<repository>:<tag>
docker push <username>/<repository>:<tag>
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to overcome this hurdle. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem, or does anyone have a potential solution to this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Heroku has [limits](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits).

Comment: Independent of Heroku, historically I've found that `docker push` has been prone to random failure once individual layers start getting above 1 GB or so.  On the application I was working on at the time, we had worked around it by shipping NLP-related data separately from the application image, and mounting it into a Docker volume.